# Made a simple linked list in C++, executable file is way too big?

Tags: c++, gcc, data-structures, linked-list

Hi I am preparing for an upcoming Data Structures course this semester. I have been practicing with some of the material and today I wrote a simple linked list. My IDE is Orwell Dev C++ 5.4.2, and the compiler is gcc 4.7.1.

My source file is only 1kb in size, and yet my generated executable is 4.5 MB! How can this be? It works fine, I am just curious as to what is going on here.

Comment: Did you enable optimizations?

Comment: Are you using anything from the standard library?

Comment: I'm using a vector<int> to pass into my linked list class

Comment: @user2676680 Ahahah, that's the problem! The implementation of `vector` is **huge.**

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Man I feel dumb haha. I wonder why it's so large.

Comment: @user2676680 Because it's not a naive implementation. stdlib classes are optimized for performance - and that involves a lot of clever tricks to be incorporated into the code.

Comment: @H2CO3 I find it very unlikely that vector will cause 4.5mb increase.

Comment: @NeilKirk In a debug build, it's not that unlikely at all. (See your first comment...)

Comment: @H2CO3 Your reasoning is that the code is optimized for performance, which isn't consistent with your later reason of debug build.

Comment: @NeilKirk Non sequitur. The implementation of vector is optimized. Still one can use the `-g -O0` flags when compiling it, no?

Comment: @user2676680: Try running `strip` on that executable (it should be in the same directory as the gcc executable). That will attempt to remove all nonessential content, but note that it will make debugging harder.

Comment: Incidentally, it's essentially trivial to create massive executables with tiny programs (think `static int huge[900000001] = {1};`).

Comment: I ran strip on it. It reduced the file size from 4.5MB to 527KB. Who knows what the problem was. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you've solved it. I'd like to add for a fairer representation of the amount of code generated by the compiler you can use `size`.  This will give you the .text size.